# How to make RDP session close popup box show before closing session again?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, rdp

I accidentally checked the check box to not show the close session popup box anymore when I "X" out of my RDP session; however, I would like to show this again.

How can I get this close session popup box to show again in RDP?

Thank you!